# Nodemailer Not receiving mail

Tags: node.js, smtp, sendmail, nodemailer

i have been trying nodemailer. I got stuck.
It runs the console log, i dont get any errors or anything.
req.body is filled with data.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport();

    app.post('/contact-form', sendMail = function (req, res) {

        transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'req.body.contactEmail',
            to: 'mymail@mail.com',
            subject: 'Message from ' + req.body.contactEmail,
            text: req.body.contactMsg + 'my contact information: ' + req.body.contactEmail + " " + req.body.contactNummer

        }),function(error, response) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            }
        }
        console.log(req.body.contactMsg);
    });
```

Comment: Where are you setting your transport parameters? Hostname, port, auth, etc?

Comment: I was using direct transport. I guess i should use a smtp provider...

_Using direct transport is not reliable as outgoing port 25 used is often blocked by default. Additionally mail sent from dynamic addresses is often flagged as spam. You should really consider using a SMTP provider._

Answer (score 1):

make it easier go to this and keep ON. https://myaccount.google.com/security

scroll down to this page and you will get Allow less secure apps: ON, just ON and it will work. here is the full code--

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

// Contact  of contact us 
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
   

        var mailOpts, smtpTrans;

        //Setup Nodemailer transport, I chose gmail. Create an application-specific password to avoid problems.
        smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            //  host:'smtp.gmail.com',
            //  port:465,
            // secure:true,
            auth: {
                user: "xxxx@gmail.com",
                pass: "xxxxxxx"
            }
        }));
        var mailoutput = "<html>\n\
                        <body>\n\
                        <table>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>Name: </td>" + req.body.form_name + "<td></td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>Email: </td><td>" + req.body.form_email + "</td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>MN: </td>" + req.body.form_phone + "<td></td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                        <td>Messge: </td>" + req.body.form_message + "<td></td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                        </table></body></html>";
        //Mail options
        mailOpts = {
            to: "NameOfYourWebsite <xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
            subject: req.body.form_subject,
            html: mailoutput
        };

        smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, res) {
            if (error) {
                // res.send("Email could not send due to error" +error);
                return console.log(error);
            }
        });
        //console.log('Message sent successfully!');
            res.render('contact.ejs');
    });
    //console.log(query.sql);

});
```